# Error in if/else statement MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help making an if/else statement work in mysql
The if statement works proper, but the else statement buggs. I browers tells me

**"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /var/www/domane/public_html/app/save.php on line 48"** - which is the else line

It's supposed to get the current value of the row, and then add it to the new value and update it

```
<?php

$dsn = "databasename";
$username="username";
$password="password"; 

try {
  $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
  $conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
}

//------------------------ Does the category already exist in dietTbl? -------------------------
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS subjectcount FROM dietTbl WHERE day=CURDATE()";

try {
                             $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
                             $st->bindValue(":mainsubject",$mainSubject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                             $st->execute();
                             $row=$st->fetch();
                             $subjectcount=$row["subjectcount"]; // if >0 the yes, the category already exists
} catch (PDOException $e) {
                             echo "Server Error - try again!".$e->getMessage();
};

//------------------------ If it dosn't, insert it into dietTbl -------------------------
if ($subjectcount==0) {

$sql="INSERT INTO dietTbl (day, vegetables, fullgrain, milk, water) values (:day, :vegetables, :fullgrain, :milk, :water)";

try {

  $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $st->bindValue(":day",$_POST["day"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->bindValue(":vegetables",$_POST["vegetables"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->bindValue(":fullgrain",$_POST["fullgrain"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->bindValue(":milk",$_POST["milk"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->bindValue(":water",$_POST["water"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $st->execute();
                             } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                                          echo "Server Error - try again!".$e->getMessage();
                             }
};

//------------------------ If it already exists, update dietTbl -------------------------
else {

SELECT SUM(vegetables) AS totalvegetables, SUM(fullgrain) AS totalfullgrain, SUM(milk) AS totalmilk, SUM(water) AS totalwater FROM dietTbl



  $sql="UPDATE INTO dietTbl (vegetables, fullgrain, milk, water) values (:vegetables+totalvegetables, :fullgrain+totalfullgrain, :milk+totalmilk, :water+totalwater)";

try {

  $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $st->bindValue(":vegetables",$_POST["vegetables"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->bindValue(":fullgrain",$_POST["fullgrain"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->bindValue(":milk",$_POST["milk"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->bindValue(":water",$_POST["water"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->execute();
                             } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                                          echo "Server Error - try again!".$e->getMessage();
                             }




};

echo "Information saved";
$conn=null; //Close database connection

?>
```

Comment: Remove the `;` on line before.

Comment: Thanks. Got rid of that error. Is it the proper way to store the existing values? Because if doesn't seem to work "SELECT SUM(vegetables) AS totalvegetables, SUM(fullgrain) AS totalfullgrain, SUM(milk) AS totalmilk, SUM(water) AS totalwater FROM dietTbl
"

Comment: Already seen too many error in your code before going for that first fix 
Remove ; from line 24, 45, 71

Comment: @Christoffer you have to use group by if you use sum.

Comment: Made it work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From this part of code:

```
};

//------------------------ If it already exists, update dietTbl ----------

else {
```

remove ";"

Comment: mentioned in comment already